# OrientDB : Can't find symbol OGraphDatabase

Tags: orientdb

I searched some examples on the Internet and many of them use the OGraphDatabase. However, when these code file was compiled, a exception that says cant find the symbol of "OGraphDatabase" was throwed.
Blow is the source code:

```
public class TestTreeGraph {
static OGraphDatabase db;
//static int i=0;
//static ODocument currentNode;

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    String dbpath="/Users/wuguirongsg/orientdb/orientdbgraph";
    File dbfile = new File(dbpath);

    if(!dbfile.exists()){
        //dbfile.mkdirs();
        db = new OGraphDatabase("local:"+dbpath).create();
        db = new OGraphDatabase("local:"+dbpath).open("admin", "admin");
    }else{
        db = new OGraphDatabase("local:"+dbpath).open("admin", "admin");
    }

    ODocument rootNode = db.createVertex().field("id", 0);
    int i=1;
    createNode(rootNode,i);

    db.setRoot("treegraph", rootNode);
}

private static void createNode(ODocument node,int i){
    if(i>=20){
        System.out.println("i>=10================== back ");
        return ;
    }
    ODocument leftNode = db.createVertex().field("id", i + "_vertex_left");
    System.out.println("create "+i + "_vertex_left ");
    ODocument rightNode = db.createVertex().field("id", i + "_vertex_right");
    System.out.println("create "+i + "_vertex_right ");
    ODocument edgeleft = db.createEdge( node, leftNode);
    ODocument edgeright = db.createEdge( node, rightNode);
    edgeleft.save();
    edgeright.save();
    //currentNode = leftNode;
    System.out.println("go left");
    createNode(leftNode,i+1);
    System.out.println("go right");
    createNode(rightNode,i+1);
    System.out.println("==================");
}
```

}

Comment: Hi Qinger, which version of OrientDB are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

OGraphDatabase has been deprecated ages ago. You can use OrientGraph.

Example

```
String dbpath="C:/test";
OrientGraphFactory factory = new OrientGraphFactory("plocal:"+dbpath);

// if the database doesn't exist it is created and opened
// if the database exists, it is opened
OrientGraph db = factory.getTx();

// inserting a vertex
Vertex rootNode=db.addVertex("class:V");
rootNode.setProperty("myId","0");

db.shutdown();
```

[image]